# Lumen/Laravel Eloquent hasManyThrough nested results

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, has-many-through, lumen

I`m trying to achieve a nested result using Laravel Eloquent.

My logic:
Cities, Neighbourhoods, Blocks

A city has many neighbourhoods

A neighbourhood has many blocks

The result that I want to acomplish:

```
City
 Neighbourhoods
  Blocks
```

The data shoud be:

```
[
  {

    id: 1,
    name: "New York",
    neighbourhoods: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "Neighbourhood 1",
        city_id: 1,
        blocks: [
          {
            id: 1,
            name: "Neighbourhood 1 Block 1",
            neighbourhood_id: 1
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            name: "Neighbourhood 1 Block 2",
            neighbourhood_id: 1
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Neighbourhood 2",
        city_id: 1,
        blocks: [
          {
            id: 3,
            name: "Neighbourhood 2 Block 1",
            neighbourhood_id: 2
          },
          {
            id: 4,
            name: "Neighbourhood 2 Block 2",
            neighbourhood_id: 2
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Models:

City.php

```
public function neighbourhood()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Neighbourhood');
}

public function block()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Block', 'App\Neighbourhood', 'city_id', 'neighbourhood_id', 'id');
}
```

Neighbourhood.php

```
public function city()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\City');
}

public function block()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Block');
}
```

Block.php

```
public function neighbourhood()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Neighbourhood');
}
```

The actual result gives me this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Ney York",
        "neighbourhoods": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "city_id": 1,
                "name": "Heighbourhood 1"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "city_id": 1,
                "name": "Heighbourhood 2"
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "city_id": 1,
                "name": "Păcurari"
            }
        ],
        "blocks": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Heighbourhood 1 Block 1",
                "neighbourhood_id": 1,
                "city_id": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Heighbourhood 1 Block 2",
                "neighbourhood_id": 1,
                "city_id": 1
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to get the results nested. Is there a way to do this? I`m missing something?

Of course that it can me done with PHP foreach loop but this will be manual job. I wonder if I can get the results this way directly from the query.

Thank you.

## SOLUTION:

```
$result = City::with('neighbourhoods.blocks')->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
$result = City::with('neighbourhoods.blocks')->get();
```

You can do nested [relationship queries](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) with dot notation.

Comment: Oh my god! You don't know how much you saved me! Thank you very very much!